# Populate google.visualization.DataTable for a AnnotatedTimeLine using JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, google-visualization

I have a HttpHandler which returns some JSON in (i think) the correct format for a [google.visualization.DataTable](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable), but the [AnnotatedTimeLine](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) fails to work?

This is the JSON returned by the Handler:

```
{cols: [{id: 'DATE', label: 'Date', type: 'date'}, {id: 'KEYWORD51', label: 'vw cheltenham', type: 'number'}, {id: 'KEYWORD52', label: 'volkswagen cheltenham', type: 'number'}, {id: 'KEYWORD61', label: 'vw dealer cheltenham', type: 'number'}], rows: [{c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 13)}, {v: 20}, {v: 1}, {v: 2}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 14)}, {v: 19}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 15)}, {v: 19}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 16)}, {v: 18}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 17)}, {v: 17}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 18)}, {v: 17}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 19)}, {v: 12}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 20)}, {v: 13}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 21)}, {v: 11}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 22)}, {v: 10}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 23)}, {v: 10}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 24)}, {v: 8}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 25)}, {v: 6}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 26)}, {v: 6}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 27)}, {v: 5}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 28)}, {v: 4}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 29)}, {v: 4}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 30)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 1)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 2)}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 3)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 4)}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 5)}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 6)}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 7)}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 8)}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 9)}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 10)}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 11)}, {v: 0}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 12)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 1}]}]}
```

This is the Javascript, I used JQuery to get the JSON, have also tried $.getJSON()

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['annotatedtimeline'] });

google.setOnLoadCallback(loadGraph);

function loadGraph() {

    $.get("/GraphDataHandler.axd", function(response) {
         drawGraph(response);
    });

}

function drawGraph(response) {
    var visualization = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response, 0.6);
    visualization.draw(data, { title: 'Rankings', titleX: 'Date', titleY: 'Position', displayAnnotations: false, allowRedraw: true });
}
```

But, if I write the same JSON to the page like below it works fine!?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var gData = {cols: [{id: 'DATE', label: 'Date', type: 'date'}, {id: 'KEYWORD51', label: 'vw cheltenham', type: 'number'}], rows: [{c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 13)}, {v: 20}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 14)}, {v: 19}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 15)}, {v: 19}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 16)}, {v: 18}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 17)}, {v: 17}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 18)}, {v: 17}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 19)}, {v: 12}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 20)}, {v: 13}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 21)}, {v: 11}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 22)}, {v: 10}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 23)}, {v: 10}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 24)}, {v: 8}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 25)}, {v: 6}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 26)}, {v: 6}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 27)}, {v: 5}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 28)}, {v: 4}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 29)}, {v: 4}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 3, 30)}, {v: 2}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 1)}, {v: 2}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 2)}, {v: 1}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 3)}, {v: 2}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 4)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 5)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 6)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 7)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 8)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 9)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 10)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 11)}, {v: 0}]}, {c: [{v: new Date(2010, 4, 12)}, {v: 2}]}]};
//]]>
</script>
```

Please advise how I can get it to work correctly using a the JSON calls?

Thanks

Comment: `getJSON` gives the same issue? Do you get any error messages on the console?

Comment: when using the $.getJSON, the call back function fails to fire, but Firebug give me response code 200 OK from the handler in the console and I can view the JSON data.

Comment: I have tried changing the handler Content-Type to application/json; charset=utf-8

But that has not helped using either $.getJSON or $.get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the reason, but make sure that you produce valid JSON. I see in the string that the keys are not enclosed in quote, but they must be (they have to be *strings*), in order to be valid JSON.

E.g. from

```
{cols: [{id: 'DATE', label: 'Date', type: 'date'}, ...]}
```

to

```
{"cols": [{"id": "DATE", "label": "Date", "type": "date"}, ...]}
```

And try again with `.getJSON()`.

---

The reason why it works if you put it directly in your code is probably because the keys don't need to be quoted in JS (but as *JSON string* it would be invalid!).

**Update:**

`getJson` uses [`.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the JSON string. As you can see in the documentation, it only accepts valid JSON which your string is **not**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the Google json notation is a little different.

Comment: Felix, you are correct, its not JSON, its a Javascript object. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it.

By adding:

```
var json = eval("(" + response + ")");
```

To this function:

```
function drawGraph(response) {

var visualization = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

var json = eval("(" + response + ")");    

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json, 0.6);

visualization.draw(data, { title: 'Rankings', titleX: 'Date', titleY: 'Position', displayAnnotations: false, allowRedraw: true });

}
```

This was using JQuery $.get()

Thanks

Comment: Strange. If it works with `eval` it should also work with `getJSON`. If you can avoid `eval` do so, if really no other way works, be happy that you found a solution ;)

Comment: Read here and you know why `getJSON` did not work (`getJSON` uses `parseJSON`) : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ It really would be better to generate valid JSON instead of using `eval`.